# dl margins not honored by webkit in @media print?

Tags: html, css, printing, webkit

I'm having a problem with margins around a dl contained in a width-constrained div.  Screen media renders dl margins predictably, but when printed, the dl margins are ignored, bleeding outside the expected boundary to the natural page margins.  I'd like to know that there's some error in my CSS or HTML and that this can be fixed, but the code seems correct to me, and works as expected in Firefox -- just not in Safari and Chrome.  The code is below but since you have to view in both screen and print to see, here's a link that works for now: http://dgc.bikeshed.us/dl.html

[edit: removed angle brackets in question]

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

<style>

@media screen {
    #main {
        width: 40em;
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 8.5in;
    }
    #main {
        width: 5.5in;
        margin: auto;
    }
}

dl {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

dt, dd {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

dt {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

dd {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

div#main {
    border: 1px solid #f88;
}
</style>

    <h1>DL test</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <p>
This minimal page illustrates what appears to be a WebKit bug with <code>dl</code> styling for printed media.
      </p>
      <p>
We set differing page width and margin for <code>@media screen</code> and <code>@media print</code>, and show a paragraph of text (this intro) to highlight where the margins should lie. Then we create a typical floated definition list, to align the <code>dl</code> in a two-column layout.  It should look predictable in all browsers, with the margins of the <code>dl</code> below aligned with this paragraph.  The whole is bounded by a red box, again to highlight the correct margin.
      </p>
      <dl>
        <dt>lorem</dt>
        <dd>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget ipsum nec turpis viverra ornare. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In malesuada turpis eu tempus blandit. Donec varius est vitae orci maximus, in faucibus odio fringilla. Pellentesque fermentum accumsan ullamcorper. Nulla dictum sem non lorem tempor, eget interdum augue tempus. Proin quis sapien euismod, luctus augue non, ullamcorper urna. Integer dignissim imperdiet fringilla. Aenean sit amet mattis orci. Cras nec velit rutrum mi aliquam cursus a id velit. Morbi gravida risus molestie orci lacinia pretium. Nulla eleifend quis lacus sit amet tristique.
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <p>
<b>Now print the page, and look at the PDF preview.</b>  The <code>dl</code> (the <code>dd</code>) exceeds the right margin, bumping against the natural page margin.  What's more, if we style the <code>@media print</code> <code>dl</code> separately, that style is ignored.  And if we style the <code>dl</code> in <code>@media screen</code>, that style applies to the printed media as well, and cannot be overridden by <code>@media print</code>.  I see this in both Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X 10.8.5, but not in Firefox.  The problem seems to be in applying width; the screen vs. print layout is distinctly different with or without the floats.  It's as if the <code>dl</code>'s <code>width</code> property is applied to the page width in print media, instead of to the container width.
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `word-break: break-word;` on the container (within `@media` print) does the trick for me in Chrome 37.

Comment: Interesting; I guess a webkit-specific workaround for a webkit-specific problem isn't too surprising. But is it correct? It still seems dysfunctional to me, and while I'll happily use the workaround in my own site I'm still wondering whether this should be reported. :/